# How to calculate the CodeSha256 of aws lambda deployment package before uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When you call `aws lambda get-function --function-name FunctionName`, you'll see a `CodeSha256` key. I don't know what it's Sha256'ing, though. It doesn't match `shasum -a 256 FunctionName.zip`, where `FunctionName.zip` is the package I had uploaded.

What I'd like to be able to do, for an existing lambda, is generate the sha256 from the code I'm about to upload that would match the sha256 amazon gives back in `get-function`. Any help is appreciated, as I haven't been able to find any information on this anywhere, except for Amazon saying it's "the SHA256 hash of the deployment package"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. All the methods for generating a sha 256 hash output it in hex, but amazon is returning it in base64.

So, to totally answer my own question, here's how to (with node), check to see if you're about to upload the same zip.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: 'us-west-2'
});

var lambdaName = 'CreatePost';
var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tmp/create-post.zip');

lambda.getFunction({
    FunctionName: lambdaName
}, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return process.exit(1);
    }
    var lambdaSha256 = data.Configuration.CodeSha256;

    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .on("data", function (chunk) {
        shasum.update(chunk);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        var sha256 = shasum.digest('base64');
        if (sha256 === lambdaSha256) {
            console.log("No need to upload, sha hashes are the same");
        } else {
            console.log("That needs to be uploaded again son.")
        }
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now in python pls :)

Answer (score 41):

As stated above, need to encode in base64. Here is a bash one-liner:
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary _your_file_path_ | openssl enc -base64

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've been searching for this for ages.

Comment: I found that `penssl sha256 -binary _your_file_path_ | openssl enc -base64` command also works. 
My openssl version is `OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023)`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a method using basic utilities on GNU/Linux:

```
cat function.zip |sha256sum |cut -d' ' -f1 |xxd -r -p |base64
```

The components may be familiar:

- `cut` isolates the checksum value
- `xxd` converts base16 to binary (reverse hex dump)
- `base64` converts binary to base64

Comment: Thanks. Just adding the command to do in reverse order. `echo -n "<SHA-FROM-LAMBDA>"|base64 -d |xxd -p`

Answer (score 3):

This will never work because of this:
[Why does Zipping the same content twice gives two files with different SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714139/why-does-zipping-the-same-content-twice-gives-two-files-with-different-sha1)

I ran into same issue trying to use the SHA from the zip.  You will always get a different SHA.

Comment: this is the correct (if unsatisfying) answer to the question asked, but I suspect not what most other punters are looking for.

Comment: Yeah the same is true for .jar files as well (which are just .zip files with a different name). 
BUT as long as you dont re-zip the folder after computing the SHA and before uploading it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In python, the same shasum from aws lambda

```
ldata = ''
with open(localfilepath,'rb') as f:
    ldata = f.read()

    # openssl equivalent command used
    # $openssl dgst -sha256 -binary <binary_file> | openssl enc -base64

    if ldata:
        m = hashlib.sha256()
        m.update(ldata)
        s3_digest = m.digest()
        local_codesha256 = b64encode(s3_digest)
```

To verify, with the aws env set correctly,(assuming, aws token and creds are set correctly for this cli to work) compare the CodeSha256. ( using python boto3 client to get lambda details.)

```
 $ aws lambda get-function --function-name <functionname>
{
    "Configuration": {
        "FunctionName": "-----------",
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us--1:----:function:-----",
        "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::-------:role/-------------",
        "Handler": "--------- ",
        "CodeSize": 10042831,
        "Description": "",
        "Timeout": 300,
        "MemorySize": 3008,
        "LastModified": "2019-10-09T23:44:08.222+0000",
        "CodeSha256": "aAMvEdR/MSq0x89LzD0L37+AZceFzhtrb9eymqczAh8=",
        "Version": "$LATEST",
        "Environment": {
            "Variables": {
            ...
             }
         }
    ..}
    .}
```

aws lambda list

```
response = None
resp_functions = []
lc = boto3.client('lambda',
                  aws_access_key_id=<-----> ,
                  aws_secret_access_key=<--->,
                  aws_session_token=<--->,
                  region_name=<--->)
try:
    response = lc.list_functions()
    while True:
        resp_functions.extend(response['Functions'][:])
        # copy the function and iterate with next marker
        if 'NextMarker' in response:
            response = lc.list_functions(Marker=response['NextMarker'])
        else:
            break

except Exception as ex:
    raise ex
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in java try the following:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Base64;

public class CodeHash {

    public static String fileSha256ToBase64(String path2file)  {

        try {
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(new File(path2file).toPath());
            MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            digester.update(data);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digester.digest());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not compute Sha256 for file in path: " + path2file);
        }
    }
}
```

For CDK users you can call this from within the infrastructure code.