# Create two zip with same hash for different files with same contents

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci

In a GitLab pipeline I create a virtualenv, install my dependencies, and zip the result. The resulting zip is used in Terraform to be deployed as an AWS Lambda. This all works at the moment. But now, everytime I run my pipeline, Terraform states that the hash of the zip changed, and it want to redeploy the lambda. It had to do with the fact that the `filebase64sha256` of the zip had changed.

If you zip one file, and you zip another file with the same contents, those two zips or their hashes do not equal. In a GitLab pipeline the files from the repository are refetched everytime a pipeline runs, therefore having different files, same contents.

Can you help me create identical hashes for zip with files of identical content?

I tried using `zip -X`, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Also, I looked into other ways of deploying a AWS Lambda using Terraform, for example using S3 buckets, but there the same problem occurs: how does Terraform know the contents of the zip stayed the same to update the file in S3?

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714139/why-does-zipping-the-same-content-twice-gives-two-files-with-different-sha1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Zipping the same content twice gives two files with different SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714139/why-does-zipping-the-same-content-twice-gives-two-files-with-different-sha1)